# Is there a hypernym for person or system?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Say for example I would like to say that my system supports granting access credentials to **both people and systems**; can I express that in a single term?

Comment: You can use “external actors” or maybe just actors (but I think external actors is better)

Comment: "Actors" is the first thing that comes to mind here. +1 @Jim.

Comment: I would prefer "entities" to "actors".

Comment: There are single words you could use in place of that, like "actors", "entities", "applicants", but none will be as clear or specific as the original. I prefer clarity over brevity in most situations.

Comment: As opposed to granting access credentials to what? Unless there is a different group of things that it does not support (not people or systems—and I don't know what that would be—dogs?), you can just say "my system supports [the] granting [of] access credentials." There is no need to enumerate a list unless you also discuss something that doesn't belong.

Comment: @Jim would you please answer the question; I'm going to choose your answer =)